# Laravel 8 Log Viewer

Tags: logging, duplicates, laravel-8, subdirectory, log-viewer

I am using the rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer package for my log viewer currently.
I faced duplicate info at the folder part when I have multiple sub-directory for my log file.
[image]

I found out that it's looping my directory
**pos->laravel->log->register**

Hence, it's showing duplicate.

Is there anyone facing the same issue with me? Any solutions for it? sorry for my broken english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had rewrite the `directoryTreeStructure` function to match my needs. Thanks.